# Get referring url to facebook iframe tab

Tags: facebook, iframe, refer

Is it possible to get the referring URL to a Facebook page tab?

Right now the referring url is always http://static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=5 and I can't find any documentation about this subject. Is facebook providing this param (I can't find it in the signed_request for example). or is there any workaround? for example would it work if i used a canvas app vs an iframe tab?

Answer (score 2):

> for example would it work if i used a canvas app vs an iframe tab?

Nope, the are both loaded in pretty much the same way.

If you have control over the links pointing to your canvas/page tab app, then you can add the "app_data" parameter to those links – that is passed through to your app when Facebook loads it – and then just evaluate that to differentiate between different points of origin.

If it’s about outside links from somewhere on the web – then there’s no way I know of to get an actual referrer, since it’s always Facebook “linking” to your app in the iframe.

*Could* be that there’s some info in your app’s insights, but I haven’t checked them out from that perspective yet.